# How to set a proxy when using SoapPortClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, soap, proxy

I'm trying to execute a function using a Soap Port Client object (from an external WebService), and I need to set a proxy (address and credentials) for it. Because when I test the app (not on localhost), the WS functionality doesn't work.

```
    Namespace.WebService.SoapPortClient foo = new Namespace.WebService.SoapPortClient();
    short cod_error;
    string des_error;
    string url = "";
    int fooNumber = 10;
    url = foo.Execute(fooNumber, out cod_error, out des_error);

...code continues
```

In the above example, I need to set a proxy for 'foo'. I've tried with foo.Proxy but this property doesn't exists in the SoapPortClient.

Thank you all!

Comment: Could you share your code or elaborate more on your problem?
It's very hard to tell or suggest something without seeing the code.

Comment: Ok! I added a piece of code, hope you understand. Thanks!

Comment: SoapPortClient is it object of some kind of library? If so, which one? 
Maybe you can find some refence in documentation to this problem?

Comment: SoapPortClient is the name of the external WS. Now I'm getting the following error: The content type text/hml of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8).

Comment: Maybe is a problem with the framework? Or something wrong with the web.config configuration?

Comment: Please update your question with the latest information. Since you are getting an error you probably did something to get there, right?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments and problem I realized that you are talking about WCF. 
Regards to your latest problem:

> Now I'm getting the following error: The content type text/HTML of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/XML; charset=utf-8)

My first suggestion would be to check that the user you're running the WCF client under has access to the resource.

Can't say much since it's very hard to say something without seeing the config file or code in general.